# Скачивание картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть картинки, после клика на картинку выполняется код:

```
var isAdmin = confirm("Скачать");
```

Как сделать чтобы, когда `confirm` возвращает `true` начиналось скачивание картинки на которую нажали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Чтобы позволить пользователю загружать изображение или другой файл вы
>   можете использовать HTML5 атрибут `download`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951326/save-image-to-users-disk-using-javascript/37521282#37521282

Можно эмулировать такую загрузку.

```js
function saveUrlAsFile(url, fileName) {    
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.click();
}

$('img').on('click',function(e){
    var isAdmin = confirm("Скачать?");
    if(isAdmin){
        saveUrlAsFile($(e.target).attr('src'), 'image.jpg');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img width="100" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000567859274/3d56eadbc1e389780a95c74189ebfa64.jpeg" />
<img width="100" src="https://shkolazhizni.ru/img/content/i133/133607_or.jpg" />
```

IE [не поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)

Comment: Просто топ) Век живи век учись :D

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('img').on('click',function(e){
    var isAdmin = confirm("Скачать");
    if(isAdmin){
        document.location.href = $(e.target).attr('src');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="100" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000567859274/3d56eadbc1e389780a95c74189ebfa64.jpeg" />

<img width="100" src="https://shkolazhizni.ru/img/content/i133/133607_or.jpg" />
```

А дальше магия со стороны сервера (На примере PHP):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="123.jpg"');
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что ссылки у всех картинок разные

Comment: Скачивание не начинается, просто открывается картинка

Comment: Что бы она скачивалась (а не открывалась) необходимо что бы сервер указал в заголовке:
`Content-Disposition: attachment;`
Сделать это можно как в back-end так и в настройках вебсервера.